# Treeview node with transparent text background instead of default white

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, custom-draw

I am using custom draw to try and create transparent tree view ( for now I am testing when  Visual Styles are enabled ).

My `CDDS_PREPAINT` handler works fine, tree has parent's background bitmap drawn properly.

I tried to add `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` handler where I use `SetBkColor( ((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->hdc, TRANSPARENT );` and return `CDRF_NEWFONT`, but that failed. Node is drawn with default white background.

How can I make item's text background transparent?

Thank you.

Best regards.

*Below is the illustrative code snippet:*

```
switch( ((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->dwDrawStage  )
{
case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    {
        DrawThemeParentBackground(
            ((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->hdr.hwndFrom,
            ((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->hdc,
            &((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->rc );

        // since tree is in dialog box we need below statement
        SetWindowLongPtr( hDlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, (LONG_PTR)CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW );
        return TRUE;

    }
    break;
case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT :  // how to properly handle this ???
    {   
        SetBkMode( ((LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->hdc, TRANSPARENT );

        SetWindowLongPtr( hDlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, (LONG_PTR)CDRF_NEWFONT );
        return TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting `lParam` to a `LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW` and setting the `clrTextBk` member to `CLR_NONE`?

Comment: @user1793036: Yes I have tried it, and the background color turns out black, as I have expected. Thank you for trying to help. Best regards.

Comment: What happens when you return a white brush?
  return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));

Comment: @Eejin: Where should I return white brush?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unfortunately, this is not easily possible without drawing the items yourself, sorry.**

It turns out the Tree View Control has traditionally used [`ExtTextOut()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162713.aspx) function internally to draw the item titles. This function takes an explicit flags parameter, where value `ETO_OPAQUE` says that "*the current background color should be used to fill the rectangle*".

Because this option is passed as an extra flag and not determined by looking at the current GDI background mode, you can't use [`SetBkMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162965.aspx) in a custom draw handler to work around this. The background color property of a DC does not support alpha channel either, so it cannot be just set transparent.

Since Common Controls version 6.0 and themed window decorations, this is a bit different, but still not useful in this case: the control just calls [`DrawThemeBackground()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) with the `TVP_TREEITEM` part and the rest is handled according to the theme being used. I see e.g in the default Aero theme in Windows 8.1 that there is this entry:

```
ClassID  | PartID       | StateID      | Property        | Value
---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------
TreeView | TVP_TREEITEM | TREIS_NORMAL | FILLCOLOR:COLOR | 255, 255, 255
```

---

**So, what are the alternatives?**

There is always an option to return `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT` for the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` event and do all the display operations yourself. But then you need to take care of drawing even the lines, [+] boxes, selection and focus rectangles and everything else.

Another option might be to leave the title text stored in the control empty, then add it in `CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT` - i.e. use [`TVM_GETITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773610.aspx) with `wParam=TRUE` to get the text rectangle and draw the real text there after everything else has been already painted by the control. But this method fails too, because some tiny opaque rectangle is apparently drawn even for empty text. You'd need to erase that artifact first, only then proceed with drawing the text youself. Coming up with a code which does work for all combinations of item state seemed tricky.

Comment: Damn... Everything you stated I have tried earlier, and I agree with you that this would be a lot of work... Upvoted for now. I will wait until bounty expires before officially accepting, in desperate hope that some miracle will happen. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, I feel your pain - stuff like this *should* be simple, right? I did some further research into how the modern themed Common Controls do this (answer updated), but, well, the result is still the same...